# Error when trying to run Memgraph under Ubuntu on WSL: "System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate."

Tags: memgraphdb

My setup is Windows 11 with WSL2 and Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.79.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 x86_64). I'm following the [instructions for installing Memgraph on Ubuntu](https://memgraph.com/docs/memgraph/install-memgraph-on-ubuntu)
but I keep getting the error:

```
mike@wks1:~$ wget https://download.memgraph.com/memgraph/v2.5.1/ubuntu-22.04/memgraph_2.5.1-1_amd64.deb
--2023-01-27 09:26:51--  https://download.memgraph.com/memgraph/v2.5.1/ubuntu-22.04/memgraph_2.5.1-1_amd64.deb
Resolving download.memgraph.com (download.memgraph.com)... 172.67.130.22, 104.21.7.96, 2606:4700:3034::6815:760, ...
Connecting to download.memgraph.com (download.memgraph.com)|172.67.130.22|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 17578738 (17M) [application/x-www-form-urlencoded]
Saving to: ‘memgraph_2.5.1-1_amd64.deb’

memgraph_2.5.1-1_amd64.deb    100%[=================================================>]  16.76M  18.3MB/s    in 0.9s

2023-01-27 09:26:52 (18.3 MB/s) - ‘memgraph_2.5.1-1_amd64.deb’ saved [17578738/17578738]

mike@wks1:~$ sudo dpkg -i memgraph_2.5.1-1_amd64.deb
[sudo] password for mike:
Selecting previously unselected package memgraph.
(Reading database ... 24112 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack memgraph_2.5.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking memgraph (2.5.1-1) ...
Setting up memgraph (2.5.1-1) ...
Don't forget to switch to the 'memgraph' user to use Memgraph
......+.....+.+........+......+...+...+.......+......+......+.........+.........+...+..+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++*......+...+...+...+............+...+.......+...+...........+...+.+.........+...+...+...........+...+.......+...............+...+.....+......+.+...+......+..+...............+.............+..+....+...+.....+.+.....+.......+..............+.+...+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++*..+.+........+......+.+........+............+.............+.............................+......+..........+......+......+........+......+...............+..........+...........+.........+...+.......+.....+...+................+.....+..........+......+....................+.+............+................................+...+.+..............+.+.....+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
..............+..+......+....+..+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++*...+....+.....+.......+............+...+........+.......+........+.........+...+...+.+.....+.............+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++*.+..+..........+...+......+...........+....+...............+.....+...+.......+.....+...+..........+...+............+........+.......+.....+.+.........+..+...+.+.....+..........+..+.........+............................+..+.+.....+........................+.+................................+...+...+.+........+.......+.........+.....+.+...+...........+............+.......+..+.+..+................+.........+......+...........+.+..+.............+..+.+..+........................+....+..+.......+........+....+........+.......+......+..+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
-----
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/memgraph.service → /lib/systemd/system/memgraph.service.
mike@wks1:~$ sudo journalctl --unit memgraph
No journal files were found.
-- No entries --
mike@wks1:~$ sudo systemctl start memgraph
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
```

I've tried all of the [tips that I got by Googling](https://www.google.com/search?q=System%20has%20not%20been%20booted%20with%20systemd%20as%20init%20system%20(PID%201).%20Can%27t%20operate), but non of them didn't work. When I dual boot into Ubuntu, I have no problems. What am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The procedure for installing Memgrap using WSL and Ubuntu is different than installing Memgraph directly onto Ubuntu. There is a notice in your output that says `Don't forget to switch to the 'memgraph' user to use Memgraph`.

The command for running Memgraph under WSL is:

```
sudo runuser -l memgraph -c '/usr/lib/memgraph/memgraph'
```

Take a look at the documentation on [how to install MemgraphDB on Windows with WSL](https://memgraph.com/docs/memgraph/install-memgraph-on-windows-wsl).